# How do I show comments on-screen while streaming on my PS4?

Tags: ps4, streaming, twitch

Recently I was setting up Twitch streaming on my PS4 for the first time in a long while.  I could not get the streaming overlay (with comments on the side) to appear like it used to.  I looked through all the relevant settings I could find.

Here's an example of the overlay I'm trying to get on my screen when I broadcast:
http://snaps.vertigofx.com/044/snap_2016-11-02_08.58.24_783.png

I don't get *any* overlay.  I only get the game full screen.

Comment: Is the overlay you included the desired one or what you are getting?

Comment: That's not my screen.  It's an example of what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find out how to toggle whether comments are displayed or not, try [this](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/broadcast.html):

Under `Advanced Settings` (access by pressing the OPTIONS button):

> Display Message to Spectators and Spectators' Comments
>
> Select the checkbox to have messages to spectators and comments from spectators appear on screen.
> **Comments appear only when your screen resolution is either 1080i or 1080p.**

Additionally, from the [PS4 Broadcasting Manual](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/share/broadcast.html), it looks like this is how you get *all* comments to display, in case you want to see them all:

> To view all comments, press the SHARE button and then select [Broadcast Settings] > [View Comments].

Comment: I cannot find any option for "see comments on screen" anywhere when I start broadcasting, or in the broadcasting options or other PS4 settings.  Also, the screenshot I shared isn't my screen.  It's just a picture I found online to show you what I'm *trying* to get but cannot.  All I get is the game full screen with no overlay at all.

Comment: Weird, as thats also how i turn it on. Is it youtube only or something?